# Corrupt stack variable in C

Tags: c, function, parameters

I am passing a pointer argument to a function, the pointer value in the calling and the called function differ. To give an idea, I am writing a piece of code which looks similar to my working code -

```
void free_wrapper (char* a) {
printf ("a - %p \n", a);
free (a);
}

main () {
char a [200];
char * c = malloc (sizeof (char)*100); //some 100 bytes;

memset (a, 50, 200);
a [199]  = '\0';

/* here I write some data into the alloc'ed memory */
/* instead of writing 100 bytes I go and write beyond the boundaries */;

strcpy (c, a); //explicit use of strcpy
printf ("c - %p \n", c);
free_wrapper (c);

return 0;
}
```

When I corrupt the allocated memory, I see that the printf before free_wrapper and the printf in the free_wrapper are printing different values for the pointer.

The issue may not happen with the code I have presented here but I hit it frequently with my working code. Can somebody give me idea of different scenarios wherein the values passed as arguments on the stack get corrupted ?

Sorry for the typo, the question has been corrected.

Comment: "When I corrupt the allocated memory" <--- Don't corrupt it! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

> I see that the printf before free_wrapper and the printf in the free_wrapper are printing different values for the pointer.

You pass `a` to `free_wrapper`, but before it you write `c`, not `a`!
That is because they differ.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems with your code:

1. You are freeing something that doesn't need freeing.  You are passing your array `a` to your free_wrapper function.  This is illegal. You can only free what you called `malloc` on. So the thing to free is `c`.
2. You're overwriting the end of your buffer `c` by a large amount, due to the fact that you're copying a 200 byte buffer `a` into a 100 byte buffer `c`.  This causes your memory corruption.  Make `c` at least as large as `a`.

`char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );` Your destination should always be larger then your source buffer.  Also use the `strcpy_s` version, which check the size of your destination array.

Comment: Addressed the first issue, that was a typo. I was printing the address of "c" at both the places. I know that I am overwriting the boundary but I want to understand why would that corrupt the stack variable.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they print different values; they **are** different values. `a` is an array allocated on the stack, and `c` is dynamically allocated from the heap. (`a` is what you're passing to `free_wrapper`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you failed to notice that you're printing two different values and that's why the results are different:

```
printf ("c - %p \n", c); 
free_wrapper (a);    //This will call a printf of a
                     // a's memory location != c's memory location
```

or if you're confused on how strcpy works. [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) is only copying the contents of the strings, not making the pointers one in the same.